# Increase tag length limit to 30 characters

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

> **Note: As of 2017, the maximum character limit has been [increased to 35](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/181240). This discussion has been left in its original state for historical purposes.**

You don't have to go exotic and pull games like <s>"[Do-Don-Pachi Dai-Fukkatsu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-Don-Pachi_Dai-Fukkatsu)" (25)</s> or ["むかしむかしあるところにとてつもなく仲の悪いツインテールの姉妹姫様がいらっしゃいましたとさ](http://www.forest.impress.co.jp/article/2007/11/29/twintail.html)" (9001); even more common games like "[Need for Speed: Most Wanted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Need_For_Speed_Most_Wanted)" (30) or "[Spider-man: Shattered Dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiderman_Shattered_Dimensions)" (26) just do not fit in <s>24</s> 25 (thanks!) characters.

When you consider that this is practically the *only* form of tagging in practice for common questions, the limit becomes really painful.

Moreover, tag length is already different in SE 2.0 sites than it is in Trilogy sites (25 characters there, 24 here).

Can we, pretty please, increase the tag length limit to **30** characters? It will not fix *all* games, but then again no value does.

Comment: Don't forget scott-pilgrim-versus-the-world, duels-of-the-planeswalkers... I had a couple more, too. But I'll leave it off at that. It's not just being able to fit whole game titles, but even some of the abbreviated titles we get would fit perfectly if we just had a couple more characters.

Comment: > *but then again no value does.* -- What is the longest game name in the history of gaming?

Comment: @Juan, for every long game name one can make a longer name.

Comment: @Juan [Google search](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&expIds=17259,24472,25856,25900,26094,26425,26446,26454,26515,26563&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=longest+video+game+name&cp=21&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=f&aqi=g4g-o1&aql=&oq=longest+video+game+na&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=652e0df67dbfff88), though it is already going to be at least 110 characters to account for MMT transliterated, or ~90+ if you go by variants of the translation. In Japanese it is only 45, but they can cheat a lot more into so few characters than most roman-script languages.

Comment: Not bothering to expand past the first few in that search, `Tohoku Daigaku Mirai-Kagaku-Gijutsu-Kyodo-Kenkyu-Center Kawashima Ryuta Kyoju Kanshu: Motto Nou wo Kitaeru Otona no DS Training` is 127 characters and is not a sentence like MMT is. It's even a cartridge game! For pure English, you have `Penny Arcade Adventures: On the Rain Slick Precipice of Darkness, Episode Two` at 77.

Comment: What is it with the long Japanese names? A 251-char game that teaches you to drive: [`Simple DS Series Vol.14 The Jidousha Kyoushuujo DS -- Gendoukitsuki Jidousha, Futsuu Jidou Nirin, Oogata Jidou Nirin, Futsuu Jidousha, Fusuu Jidousha Nishuu, Chuugata Jidousha, Oogata Jidousha, Oogata Jidousha Nishuu, Oogata Tokuchuu Jidousha, Kenbiki`](http://ds.ign.com/objects/894/894374.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's been tagged declined, and the explanation has been repeatedly posted to state that the number of characters in the tags is a hard limit that cannot be changed without a significant overhaul.