# Tagging overhaul?

Tags: discussion, tags

I absolutely hate staring at the tag [assassins-creed-revel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-revel) due to the [25 char limit](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/increase-tag-length-limit-to-30-characters).  I think its atrocious and not intuitive at all for searching purposes.

What about a scheme where we split up these type of games into multiple tags?

The original tags would be broken down into:  [series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series) [game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)

Examples:

> [assassins-creed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed) [revelations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/revelations)
>   [assassins-creed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed) [brotherhood](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brotherhood)
>   [the-elder-scrolls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls) [skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim)
>   [the-elder-scrolls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls) [oblivion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oblivion)
>   [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) [wings-of-liberty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wings-of-liberty)
>   [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) [heart-of-the-swarm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heart-of-the-swarm)

Does this make things more confusing overall?  Any way to enforce that you can't just use the series tag without specifying a game in the series unless it really is a series related question?

Comment: The difference is that "Revelations", alone, as a tag is ambiguous. "Skyrim" is not.

Comment: See [SEO for AC: Revelations](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3727/6066) -- much better solution IMO.

Comment: Well the whole point of splitting up the tags is to avoid having to find the best acronym for SEO related issues so stuff like [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3574/rename-star-wars-old-republic-swtor) and [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3552/rename-star-wars-tor-star-wars-old-republic) doesn't have to happen for every big name title that comes out.  You can just do [tag:star-wars] [tag:the-old-republic] instead.

Comment: @RavenDreamer it can be argued oblivion is ambiguous as well yet we use that instead of the-elder-scrolls-oblivion.  If we get some kind of convention then we don't have to make these justifications as often

Comment: @yx. "the-elder-scrolls-oblivion" is > 25 characters. That's the biggest reason we don't use it.

Comment: @RavenDreamer so is "Assassins-Creed-Revelations". That's the whole problem here - we handle these cases inconsistently and they are frustratingly common.

Comment: Exactly, if we can come up with a standard way without having to worry about the best acronym for SEO that would be ideal.  I'm just proposing something here for discussion purposes.

Comment: Before we move forward with considering a radical solution like this, someone with some MSO rep to burn might want to use a bounty to [fish for a definitive answer to this feature request.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118280/add-method-to-expand-tags-when-used-in-the-page-title) It's probably [tag:status-declined] but knowing that for a fact makes pursuing solutions like this much more important.

Comment: if anyone wants to put a bigger bounty than 250 (that's all the rep I got on there) feel free to do so.  If not, I'll put it up in an hour or so.

Comment: @yx. honestly, 50 is fine. The point isn't the amount, it's that it exists. And starting lower allows you to keep doubling the amount weekly until *it does* get addressed. Like I said, I'd do it myself, but I would like to keep enough MSO rep to post comments.

Comment: done, 50 rep it is

Answer (score 5):

[The last time this came up](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2582/8366), badp mentioned something that I think still holds true:

> One tag per game. Two tags for a game is not how SE rolls.

Given that on one of Jeff Atwood's more recent visits, [he specifically mentioned overtagging](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3304/8366) as a problem, I  think any solution that involves more tags for a single game is not likely to be acceptable even if we feel it is a workable solution.

We already know that the 25-character limit is fixed indefinitely. Unless the SE folks are willing to spend dev time on a solution like the one LessPop links to on meta.SO, I don't think we have an alternative to [series-gamena](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series-gamena).

I do think that a two-tag approach would cause a bit of confusion: the tag wiki for the series, in particular, would require more explanation, and then we would probably be answering questions on meta as to why we need to use [assassins-creed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed) but not [madden](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/madden) or [rock-band](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rock-band). (There may be fringe cases where a game name is used by multiple series – explaining that [revelations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/revelations) applies to both Assassin's Creed: Revelations and, say, a future Ratchet & Clank: Revelations could be a big issue – but I don't think that's as important unless we can identify one that would apply now.) Unfortunately, there isn't a good way to estimate confusion about multiple tags vs. confusion with abbreviated tags. If there were, we'd have something more than opinions to work with, and maybe that would influence the SE folks.

I think a consistent policy is easier for people to understand, even if it means we have some tags that are not intuitive. I would vote to keep the one-tag-per-title rule at the expense of the longer game names.

Comment: I would agree with 1 tag per question *if* we could just have longer tags (which isn't possible according to meta.so).  This 25 char limitation is the root of all the problems we've been having with all these silly [tag SEO](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=SEO+RETAG+rename) questions.